# Not Found component emerges in every page in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created a zoom-like meeting application. I have created a 404.js component. I have added it to the Route. But it seems that it is in every page. For example when I get into the profile edit page in localhost/profile/edit, the 404.js component is together with Edit.js component in the same page. Here is my Route component:

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import asyncComponent from '../modules/AsyncFunc';
import { UserContext } from '../Context/Auth';
import authRoutes from './authRoutes';


const routes = [
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/join/:_meeting_id/:_pass/',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/JoinMeeting/index"))
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/join/:_meeting_id/',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/JoinMeeting/index"))
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/join',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/JoinMeeting/index"))
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/meeting/:_meeting_id',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/Meeting"))
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/meeting/:_meeting_id/:_pass',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/Meeting"))
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/r',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/UserRoom"))
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/r/:id',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/UserRoom"))
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/r/:id/:pass',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/UserRoom"))
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: '/r/:id/:pass/:faststart',
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/UserRoom"))
  }
]

const AppRoutes = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  return (

    <>
      <Route
        exact
        path={"/"}
        component={asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/Home/home"))}
      />
      <Route
      component={asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/404.js"))}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path={"/signin"}
        component={asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/Signin/signin"))}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path={"/signup"}
        component={asyncComponent(() => import("../pages/Signup/signup"))}
      />
      {routes.map((r, i) => {
        return <Route key={i} {...r} />
      })}


      {authRoutes.map((r, i) => {
        return <Route key={i} {...r} >
          {!token ? <Redirect to="/signin" /> : null}
        </Route>
      })}


    </>
  )
}
export default AppRoutes
```

Here is my App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from './configurations/theme';
import Routes from './configurations/routes'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import AppStyle from "./pages/style";
import Header from './pages/Header';
import { UserContext } from './Context/Auth';
import { useContext, Suspense } from 'react';
import ExSideBar from './pages/ExSideBar';
import Footer from './pages/Footer';
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import PageLoading from './UI/PageLoading/PageLoading';



    function App() {
    
      const { siteWidth, exSideBar,  } = useContext(UserContext);
    
      
      return (
        <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
          <ConfigProvider >
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <BrowserRouter>
                <AppStyle siteWidth={siteWidth} >
                  <Switch>
                    <div className="siteContainer">
    
    
                      {exSideBar
                        ?
                        <div className="exSideBar">
                          <ExSideBar />
                        </div>
                        : null}
    
    
                      <div className="bodyContainer">
    
                        <div className="mainContent">
                          <Header />
    
                          <div className="body">
                            <div className="mainContainer">
                              <Routes />
                            </div>
                          </div>
    
                        </div>
                      </div>
    
                    </div>
                  </Switch>
                  <footer className="footer">
                    <Footer />
                    {/* <center>
                    <Button onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>EN</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => changeLanguage('de')}>DE</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => changeLanguage('tr')}>TR</Button>
                  </center> */}
                  </footer>
                </AppStyle>
    
              </BrowserRouter>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </ConfigProvider>
        </Suspense>
      );
    
    }
    export default App;
```

Comment: AFAIK the order of routes is important. React router will display first route that matches. `Route` for 404 should be listed at the end and should have `path="*"` as in [this example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match)

Comment: I have put 404.js as you said at the end, and added path='*' but it stays the same

Comment: Is there any solution for this sir? I have the same problem

Comment: I must check it out @Raazescythe